# spray autochunked requests with multipart/form-data

Tags: file-upload, multipart, spray

I'm using spray-can and spray-routing to support a REST service that includes an operation to upload files. This operation accepts multipart/form-data and the formFields directive works well.
When I try to use the spray request chunking support though, I find that the formFields directive is not working as the whole multipart message is chunked and not just the one part that is large.
Has anyone got any advice on how the handle large multipart messages in spray-can?
All I can think of right now is to put the whole request data in a temp file and to use something like org.apache.commons.fileupload.MultipartStream to parse the request.